# Don’t use first differences if you expect lagged effects?

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation, lags, differencing

I’m interested in seeing if two first differenced variables are cross correlated with one another (the original data are non stationary, hence I use the first differences which I show with a DF test to be stationary). Naturally, I am also interested in seeing how the XCF changes with various lags.

I came across this article which says one may not want to use first differences if lagged effects are expected. Nowhere have I read advice like this… XCF with lags using first differenced data seems to be commonly done.

Is there a problem with running an XCF with lags using first differenced data? Ideally my goal is to maximize XCF given lag value, but this article is concerning.

[image]

Comment: why are you taking first difference in the first place?

Comment: The original data are non stationary. The first differences are stationary and therefore safe to perform correlations.

Comment: Do the original time series have unit roots? Otherwise, why take first differences? The source you quote is misleading, as deterministic trends do not warrant taking first differences.

Comment: I tested them with a DF test, assuming no drift or trend… resulted in a significantly negative beta estimate. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I cannot comment on whether the DF test specification was appropriate without seeing the data. But a significantly negative slope estimate suggests there is no unit root, the series is I(0) rather than I(1), and so differencing is unwarranted.

Comment: Apart from what Richard said, a more basic question is how did you decide to do the test without drift or trend?

Comment: My mistake. The slope was not significantly negative therefore my series has a unit root. I too am struggling with how to determine which test to use. Maybe I will write another question specifically asking that.